# select inside a case statement not works

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle12c, plsql-package

I wanted to write a select statement inside CASE THEN statement in PLSQL but it throws error. Please advise if I could write select statement inside THEN Statement.

An example  similar to my requirement looks like below

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
LV_VAR VARCHAR2(4000):=NULL;
BEGIN
LV_VAR:= CASE 
                    WHEN 1=1 THEN 
                        (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
                     ELSE
                        0
                     END;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_VAR);
END;
```

While executing , it throws error as below

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 26:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select inside CASE THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203219/select-inside-case-then)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use scalar subqueries directly in PL/SQL code, like you have shown. (Of course, you knew that already.) You must select the value `INTO` a variable, and then use it.

ALSO: You have no `case` statements in your code. You have a `case` **expression**. It just won't work quite the way you wrote it.

One alternative is to use a `case` expression within the SQL `SELECT ... INTO` statement, as David Goldman has shown in his Answer.

However, if the whole point of your exercise was to practice `case` expressions as used in PL/SQL, not inside a SQL statement, you would need to `SELECT ... INTO` a variable you declare in your code, and then use that variable in the `case` expression. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  LV_VAR VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 INTO LV_VAR FROM DUAL;
  LV_VAR:= CASE 
                WHEN 1=1 THEN 
                  LV_VAR
                ELSE
                  0
           END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_VAR);

END;
```

As you can see, I did something that is done frequently in procedural language code: Instead of declaring and using TWO variables, I only declared one. I populated it with the result of the `SELECT ... INTO` query. Then I assigned to it again in the `case` expression: in one case I assign it to itself and in the other I assign to it the value 0.

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL, you'll need to do a SELECT ... INTO.  So, to re-write your code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
LV_VAR VARCHAR2(4000):=NULL;
BEGIN

SELECT CASE 
           WHEN 1=1 then 1
                    else 0
       end
INTO LV_VAR
FROM DUAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_VAR);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to combine PL/SQL Control Statement `CASE` with SQL `CASE` Expressions. 
While it is possible to use a sub-query in `THEN` return expression of SQL `CASE`,

```
select CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN ( select 1 FROM DUAL ) 
ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL;
```

The same is not true while you use it in PL/SQL although the syntax is same.

Read the Oracle documentation for SQL , [CASE1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) and PL/SQL : [CASE2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS99972)