# Updating date column to match previous column, to show matching date to job title

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I work for a law firm and some cases can take years to complete, so I am looking to create a report which changes the job title of the person as they get promoted during the case.

Using the following guide [Select inside CASE THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203219/select-inside-case-then)

I got the job title to change as the years go on, but the date of when the job title changed is not updating properly. What it is doing is taking the first ever change date and carrying on with that which will be because I set TOP 1 I'm sure, what I want to know now is how do I tell it to work off the row where the job title, and Earnercode matches. (Below is the code I have so far)

```
SELECT
    A.STAFF_DIWOR, 
    DATEPART(YEAR, A.CHANGE_DATE) AS [Year],
    DATEPART(MONTH, A.CHANGE_DATE) AS [Month],
    A.CHANGE_DATE, A.NEW_TYPE_DIWOR,
    B.EARNERCODE, C.CATEGORYDESC
INTO 
    #TmpStaff
FROM 
    STAFF_CHANGE_HISTORY A
LEFT JOIN 
    STAFF B ON A.STAFF_DIWOR = B.DIWOR
LEFT JOIN 
    EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY C ON C.DIWOR = A.NEW_TYPE_DIWOR
WHERE 
    CHANGE_TYPE = 'EMP' 
    AND CATEGORYDESC <> 'Leavers'

SELECT
    A.MATTER_CODE, A.FE_CODE, A.FE_NAME,
    B.YEARDESC, A.PERIOD, CHRG_HRS_YTD, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 Ts.CATEGORYDESC FROM #TmpStaff Ts 
     WHERE Ts.[Year] <= (YEARDESC) AND (FE_CODE = Ts.EARNERCODE)) AS STAFF_GRADE,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Ts.CHANGE_DATE FROM #TmpStaff Ts 
     WHERE Ts.[Year] <= (YEARDESC) AND (FE_CODE = Ts.EARNERCODE)) AS ChangeDate  --This is not updating with the correct date
FROM 
    on_mat_fe_PERF A
JOIN
    PM_YEAR B ON A.FINYEARDIWOR = B.DIWOR
WHERE 
    A.MATTER_CODE = @Matter
```

I tried changing the year to CategoryDesc = CategoryDESC but that didn't work.

**Edit**:

To give an idea of what I am looking for this is what it is currently providing

```
Solicitor Newly Qualified    2018-05-03 09:15:16.100
Solicitor 1+                 2018-05-03 09:15:16.100
```

and this is what I want to get out of it

```
Solicitor Newly Qualified    2018-05-03 09:15:16.100
Solicitor 1+                 2019-07-27 09:30:16.100
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will like help us help you here.

Comment: I bet you just need to add `order by` to make your `top 1` mean something not arbitrary.  Maybe `SELECT TOP 1 Ts.CHANGE_DATE FROM #TmpStaff Ts WHERE Ts.[Year] <= (YEARDESC) AND (FE_CODE = Ts.EARNERCODE) ORDER BY CHANGE_DATE DESC`

Comment: Or maybe just `SELECT max(Ts.CHANGE_DATE) FROM #TmpStaff Ts WHERE Ts.[Year] <= (YEARDESC) AND (FE_CODE = Ts.EARNERCODE)`

Comment: if you won't mention order by clause while using top, you will end up with random top 'n'.
the correct way is to use Order By clause while using TOP 'n'.and then do other calc/logics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Avery_larry

```
SELECT max(Ts.CHANGE_DATE) FROM #TmpStaff Ts WHERE Ts.[Year] <= (YEARDESC) AND (FE_CODE = Ts.EARNERCODE)`
```

Was exactly what was needed