# I'm trying to use a select statement within a case but I have many syntax errors in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select
    column1,
    case 
        when column1 = 1 then select ename from emp where sal=2000
        when column1 = 2 then select ename from emp where sal=3000
        when column1 is null then 'NULL'
        else to_number('123')
    end as result from values (1), (2), (null);
```

> SQL compilation error: parse error line 4 at position 37 near '32'.
> syntax error line 4 at position 44 unexpected 'from'. syntax error
> line 4 at position 67 unexpected '` '. parse error line 5 at position
> 37 near '32'. syntax error line 5 at position 25 unexpected 'then'.

Answer (score 2):

The sub-queries should be in brackets as follows:

```
select
column1,
case 
    when column1 = 1 then (select ename from emp where sal=2000)
    when column1 = 2 then (select ename from emp where sal=3000)
    else to_number('123')
end as result from values (1), (2), (null);
```

Reference : [Select inside CASE THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203219/select-inside-case-then)